# signal() function in C not working properly

Tags: c, linux, terminal, signals

(code and output below) This is a program that creates 2 child processes, sends signals to each of them to basically print 2 different messages periodically. The program successfully sends signals with kill() function, but when the child prosses receive the signals, they don't execute what they're supposed to do. here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include<wait.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<signal.h>

void passage(int);
void AB(int);
//void BA(int);

bool ab = false;
bool ba = true;
int pid[2];
int I = 1;
 
void passage(int signum) //handler
{
    printf("car %d passed.\n", i);
    i++;
    if(ab == false)
    {
        printf("light1: RED | light2: GREEN\n"); 
    } else 
    {
        printf("light1: GREEN | feu2: RED\n"); 
    }
}

void AB(int sig)
{
    printf("this message doesn't print out1.\n");
    ab = !ab;
}
 
/*void BA(int sig)
{
// changer les rols des fils
    printf("this message doesn't print out2.\n");
    ba = !ba;
}*/

int main() 
{ 
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = passage;
    sigaction(SIGALRM,&action,NULL);
 
    pid[0]=fork();
    if(pid[0] != -1 )
    {
        if (pid[0]==0)
        {
            // Code of child 1
            printf("test1\n");
            
            signal(SIGUSR1,AB);
            exit(1);
        } else
        {
            pid[1]=fork();
            if(pid[1]==0)
            {
                // Code of child 2  
                printf("test2\n");
                //signal(SIGUSR2,BA);
               exit(2);
            } else
            {
                // parent precessus
                //send signals to the two childs after 3s
                printf("PONT OUVERT\n");
  
                while(1)
                { 
                    //sending signal to child 1 function to execute AB() each 3s
                    kill(pid[0],SIGUSR1);
                    //kill(pid[1],SIGUSR2);
                    alarm(3);
                    pause();
                    while ( wait(NULL) != -1 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

did I declare ab bool variable wrong? the output prints only the first condition message every 3s over and over, the ab variable is not changing and it's "false".What I'm missing, please? I really appreciate your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyw39.png)

Comment: Did you intentionally registered a signal handler for `SIGALRM` and sent `SIGUSR1`?

Comment: `signal(SIGUSR1,AB); exit(1);` Since you exit the process then no signals will be handled by that process.

Comment: @SpiderPig1297 Yes the question was to send signals to the 2 child processes each time one of them executes its function that takes 3s. the 3s timer must be done with SIGALRM, I doubt that I'm not sending the signals in the right place.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for replying, but it's the same thing if I remove the exit(1).

Comment: Removing the `exit` is not enough to stop the process from exiting. You have nothing in your code after that so the process will just exit anyway. As a test change the `exit` to call `sleep`.

Comment: You can use `sigwait()` in the child processes to suspend them until they receive a signal.

Comment: In any case your approach here is going to fail, because changing `ab` and `ba` in the child processes won't affect the values in the parent process.

Comment: @Crowman I see, then I have to change the ab before I send the signals. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kaylum I remember we used while(1) in class, not sure how it works. but I'll try sigwait() too. thanks, man!

Comment: @Crowman I think I fixed the problem, but it just prints a message once then print "Alarm clock", it's been poping for a while now, I'm afraid that it's a malware thing, is it? please

Comment: @MounirDev: I doubt it's malware, since you wrote it. I can't guess what's wrong with code I can't see, so if you're still having problems, I'd suggest asking a new question about your new problem with your new code.

Comment: in a signal handler, do not use functions that are not async safe.  `prinf()` is such a unsafe function.  Suggest using `write( 1, ... );`

Comment: regarding function: `void AB(int sig)`  the parameter: `sig` is not used.  This causes the compiler to output a warning.  Suggest the first line in the body of the function be: `(void)sig;`

Comment: in function: `void passage(int signum)`  the variable `i` is not defined`.  This is an error and causes the compile to fail.

Comment: regarding function: `void passage(int signum)`  the parameter: 'siignum' is not used. This causes the compiler to output a warning. Suggest the first line in the body of the function be: `(void)signum;`

Comment: regarding the statement: `#include <wait.h>`  It should be: `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Comment: regarding: `int I = 1;`  The variable `I` is not used anywhere in the posted code

Comment: regarding; `if(pid[0] != -1 )`  Should output a message to `stderr` indicating the failure.  Suggest: `perror( "fork failed" );`  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`